# Adjusting the width of column of table

Tags: html, css

The following code of mine has a table with two columns. The total width of the table is 800px. I would like to have an equal number of width for both my columns. Therefore I set 400px for each. But it didn't work. I think I need to amend my codes to get it. How should this be done?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>OCAAS</title>
    </head>

    <style>
        html { height: 100%; }

        body {
            background: #f5f0ed;
            font: 10px/1 Tahoma, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-aligh: center;
            BACKGROUND-POSITION: center bottom;
        }

        #image{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            clear: both;
            margin-right: 500px;
            margin-top: -250px;
            background: #green;
        }
        // amend the image
        #image div{
            width: 500px;
            height: 100px;
            float: left;
            line-height: 100px;
            text-align: center;  

        }

        #image div img{
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            max-width: 80%;
            max-height: 80%;
        }


    </style>

    <BODY>
        <table width="800px" height="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" valign="middle" width="400px">
                        <div id="image">
                            <div><img src="cat.jpg" border="0"/></div>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td align="right" valign="middle" width="400px">
                        <div id="wording">
                            <div><p>I AM NEW TO THIS</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="title">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try 50% , try to specify in %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use css for <table> :
`table{width:100%}
td{width:50%}`

Answer (score 0):

You image div width is a problem (it's wider that a column width you have specified):

```
#image div{
    width: 500px;
```

also,

```
margin-right: 500px;
```

Fix this values (use % if necessary, relative to td width as all these elements resides within the Table) to make you table `td` to align properly. Rgds,